# lxml Create XML file recursively based on another XML File

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

My goal is to Recursively create an XML File based on another XML File.
Sample Input Data as below (Original Files are ~ 10MB)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Picture Name="Template">
  <Children>
    <Shape Name="GroupLevel" ClassName="Group">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="Property1" Value="Value1" />
        <Property Name="Property2" Value="Value2" />
        <Property Name="Property3" Value="Value3" />
      </Properties>
      <ContainedObjects>
        <Shape Name="Group1" ClassName="Group">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="Property1" Value="Value1" />
            <Property Name="Property2" Value="Value2" />
            <Property Name="Property3" Value="Value3" />
          </Properties>
          <ContainedObjects>
            <Shape Name="Glue123" ClassName="Text" />
            <Shape Name="Variable1" ClassName="Variable" />
            <Shape Name="Variable2" ClassName="Variable" />
            <Shape Name="Variable3" ClassName="Variable" />
            <Shape Name="Group2" ClassName="Group">
              <Properties>
                <Property Name="Property1" Value="Value1" />
                <Property Name="Property2" Value="Value2" />
                <Property Name="Property3" Value="Value3" />
              </Properties>
              <ContainedObjects>
                <Shape Name="Group3" ClassName="RoundRect" />
              </ContainedObjects>
            </Shape>
          </ContainedObjects>
        </Shape>
      </ContainedObjects>
    </Shape>
  </Children>
</Picture>
```

1. Need to Loop Inside `Child` tag. During the Loop, if I find the `Shape` tag Whose Parent is `Children`, Create a Node with that Tag Name in a blank Root.
2. Ignore Properties / Property Nodes
3. If I find Shape tag Whose Parent is `ContainedObjects`, Create a Node `ContainedObjects` while maintaining the depth, add the `Shape` Tag Inside that `ContainedObjects` Node.
4. The actual operations involve creating a Different set of Nodes based on each Shape Tag, Which will be done at a later stage.
    For now, I am stuck at the recursive looping.

```html
<Children>
  <Shape Name="GroupLevel" ClassName="Group">
    <ContainedObjects>
      <Shape Name="Group1" ClassName="Group">
        <ContainedObjects>
          <Shape Name="Glue123" ClassName="Text" />
          <Shape Name="Variable1" ClassName="Variable" />
          <Shape Name="Variable2" ClassName="Variable" />
          <Shape Name="Variable3" ClassName="Variable" />
          <Shape Name="Group2" ClassName="Group">
            <ContainedObjects>
              <Shape Name="Group3" ClassName="RoundRect" />
            </ContainedObjects>
          </Shape>
        </ContainedObjects>
      </Shape>
    </ContainedObjects>
  </Shape>
</Children>
```

Problem Code - This Doesn't Work, I tried recursively looping, but it doesn't hold the depth/nesting of objects. Please share any pointers.

```
def RecurseXML(Data_Tree):
    for Children in Data_Tree.iterchildren():
        if Children.tag == "Shape":
            Owner       = Children.getparent().tag
            Owner       = etree.SubElement(Root_Child,Owner)
            SomeValue   = etree.SubElement(Owner,Children.tag,attrib={"Name":Children.attrib['Name']})
            Root_Child.append(SomeValue)
        if len(Children) > 0:
            RecurseXML(Children)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is good at that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Children | Shape | ContainedObjects">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

lxml allows you to run XSLT.

Comment: Hey Martin, 

Could you please point me towards a good source of learning/building XSL Templates? 
This might resolve a lot of Transformations I need to work on!

Comment: There are lots of books and courses, https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm is available for free, the author also has a video course on Udemy, although there you need to check which parts or hours are for free. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info has a larger list of resources for learning, coding and practising.